# MySQL query outputs odd rows only

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have the following PHP method that returns a JSON string from a MySQL query:

```
$sys_words_ref_join_query = mysql_query("
 SELECT user_words.*, sys_words.*
 FROM user_words, sys_words
 WHERE user_words.sys_words_ref = sys_words.sys_words_ref 
 & user_words.user_info_ref = '1'
 LIMIT 0, 7
");

$json_array = array();

while($words_obj = mysql_fetch_object($sys_words_ref_join_query)) {
 $json_array[] = $words_obj;
}

$result = json_encode($json_array);

echo $result;
```

The problem I'm having is that the `$result` is echoing only odd DB rows, eg. 1,3,5..., etc.

Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably be using a [Logical AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) (`AND`) instead of a [Bitwise AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) (`&`) in the where clause:

```
WHERE user_words.sys_words_ref = sys_words.sys_words_ref 
 AND user_words.user_info_ref = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
user_words.sys_words_ref = sys_words.sys_words_ref & user_words.user_info_ref = 1
```

implies bitwise `AND` between `sys_words.sys_words_ref` and `user_words.user_info_ref`, which is later compared to `user_words.sys_words_ref`

So you get only the rows with `user_words.sys_words_ref` matching the bitwise `AND` between these two fields which is probably only true for the odd rows (with the last bit set).

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the **mysql_query** function? I can't see there. Also try to echo this:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r ($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows in a relational database don't have an external ordering, hence have no row numbers. A RDBMS is free to use whatever internal ordering the developers wish. If you want an order, you must explicitly specify it with an [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sorting-rows.html) clause.